# Is every positive definite matrix symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

whether every positive definite matrix has to be symmetric? If not, what will be the example?

Comment: Usually, "positive definite" means "symmetric positive definite" (or Hermitian positive definite), but I think you can find examples of authors for whom "positive definite" does not necessarily imply "symmetric" (or Hermitian).

Comment: The matrix $A:=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $v^T A v > 0$ for all $v$, which may or may not be a counterexample depending on which definitions you are using. You can see this by computing $\begin{bmatrix}x & y\end{bmatrix}A\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = x^2 + y^2$

Comment: Isn't this by definition? If $f: V \to V$ is positive operator, then $(fv,v) = (v,fv)$.

Answer (score 11):

If the definition is simply $x^TAx\geq0$ for all $x $, this can fail over the reals:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end {bmatrix} $$ satisfies $x^TAx\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$.

For complex matrices, the condition $x^*Ax\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb C^n $ implies that  $A $ is selfadjoint.

Answer (score 1):

By [**definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) it is assumed to be symmetric.